# Reading Hebrew text into R using fread (data.table) or read.csv on Windows

Tags: r, import, data.table, tibble, hebrew

I am working on a Hebrew database with R functions written with data.table functionality. It works perfectly fine on MacOS, but not on Windows.

```
dt <- fread("https://pastebin.com/raw/EZ0nwk0J", encoding = "UTF-8")
```

Importing with the above command on Windows displays unicode notation (eg <U+05D1><U+05E8><U+05D0>) instead of Hebrew (ברא).

However I found an alternative that works by importing the data using the following code

```
library(readr)
dt <- read_csv("https://pastebin.com/raw/EZ0nwk0J", locale = locale(encoding = "UTF-8"))
```

But my entire code uses data.table functionality, and I don't want to (learn tibble) and reqrite the code. Is there a way to import Hebrew via fread into a data table? Thanks.